# pandas equivalent of np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause

`np.where` has the semantics of a vectorized if/else (similar to Apache Spark's `when`/`otherwise` DataFrame method). I know that I can use `np.where` on `pandas.Series`, but `pandas` often defines its own API to use instead of raw `numpy` functions, which is usually more convenient with `pd.Series`/`pd.DataFrame`.

Sure enough, I found `pandas.DataFrame.where`. However, at first glance, it has completely different semantics. I could not find a way to rewrite the most basic example of `np.where` using pandas `where`:

```
# df is pd.DataFrame
# how to write this using df.where?
df['C'] = np.where((df['A']<0) | (df['B']>0), df['A']+df['B'], df['A']/df['B'])
```

Am I missing something obvious? Or is pandas' `where` intended for a completely different use case, despite same name as `np.where`?

Comment: The docstring http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html seems to explain it reasonably well (althought it could use an example or two).  Pay attention to the short description, and the description of the `cond` and `other` arguments, but ignore the option for these arguments to be callable.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser On the second reading of the docs, I think I got it... It's something like `(df.A + df.B).where((df['A']<0) | (df['B']>0), df.A/df.B)`, right? I'll delete my question I guess.

Comment: @max: No don't delete. This will likely help someone in the future.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try:

```
(df['A'] + df['B']).where((df['A'] < 0) | (df['B'] > 0), df['A'] / df['B'])
```

The difference between the `numpy` `where` and `DataFrame` `where` is that the default values are supplied by the `DataFrame` that the `where` method is being called on ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)).

I.e.

```
np.where(m, A, B)
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
A.where(m, B)
```

If you wanted a similar call signature using pandas, you could take advantage of [the way method calls work in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects):

```
pd.DataFrame.where(cond=(df['A'] < 0) | (df['B'] > 0), self=df['A'] + df['B'], other=df['A'] / df['B'])
```

or without kwargs (Note: that the positional order of arguments is different from the `numpy` `where` [argument order](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)):

```
pd.DataFrame.where(df['A'] + df['B'], (df['A'] < 0) | (df['B'] > 0), df['A'] / df['B'])
```

Comment: if you would like to show an example in the doc string would be a great contribution !

Comment: @Jeff Just submitted a PR. Do you have any resources for understanding pandas's source code structure at a high level (e.g. extant docs/ posts on developer forums)? I read through the contribution/development docs that I found and didn't see anything resembling this kind of 5000-ft view of the source code.

Comment: And what do we do when we want a single value if condition is satisfied? We can't really say `1.where(df['A']>df['B'], other=df['C'])`

Comment: @max Make a new DataFrame with same index that is filled with ones.

Comment: @Alex, Thank you!  --I was using a pd.Dataframe instance and not the class object pd.DataFrame.  Using "pd.DataFrame" works.

Comment: "TypeError: unbound method where() must be called with DataFrame instance as first argument (got Series instance instead) " when i try to call pd.DataFrame.where( df.A == 'a', 'a', 'b'), do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @DingxinXu The last line of the answer addresses exactly this (look at the argument order).

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using *pandas'* [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) over [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where) since it is less counterintuitive (at least for me).

```
(df['A']/df['B']).mask(df['A']<0) | (df['B']>0), df['A']+df['B'])
```

Here, column `A` and `B` are added where the condition holds, otherwise their ratio stays untouched.

Answer (score 1):

#### pandas 2.2 update: [`Series.case_when`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.case_when.html#pandas.Series.case_when)

From pandas 2.2.0, the API provides a pandaic alternative to `np.where` and `np.select`.

Using `np.where`:

```
df['C'] = np.where((df['A']<0) | (df['B']>0), df['A']+df['B'], df['A']/df['B'])
```

Using [`case_when`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.case_when.html#pandas.Series.case_when):

```
cond = (df['A']<0) | (df['B']>0)
df['C'] = (df['A']/['B']).case_when([(cond, df['A']+df['B']))

# or 

df['C'] = 0 # or pd.na or any reasonable default
df['C'] = df['C'].case_when([(cond, df['A']+df['B'], 
                             (~cond, df['A']/df['B'])),])
```

You notice that `case_when` allows you to provide an arbitrary list of conditions and replacement pairs, so this can generalize to several conditions easily (much like `np.select`).