# How can I plot rows less than 0 as a different color?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe, colors

I have a dataframe with one column of data.  I'd like to visualize the data such that all the bars above the horizontal axis are `blue`, and those below it are `red`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) for selecting values above and below `0` to new columns `b` and `c`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)
data = np.random.randn(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':data})

df['b'] = df.a.where(df.a >= 0)
df['c'] = df.a.where(df.a < 0)
print (df)
          a         b         c
0  1.624345  1.624345       NaN
1 -0.611756       NaN -0.611756
2 -0.528172       NaN -0.528172
3 -1.072969       NaN -1.072969
4  0.865408  0.865408       NaN
5 -2.301539       NaN -2.301539
6  1.744812  1.744812       NaN
7 -0.761207       NaN -0.761207
8  0.319039  0.319039       NaN
9 -0.249370       NaN -0.249370

#plot to same figure
ax = df.b.plot.bar(color='b')
df.c.plot.bar(ax=ax, color='r')
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy.where you can get indices at which data is below 0: `np.where(x < 0)` and over 0: `np.where(x >= 0)`, thus you will get two not overlapping arrays, which you can visualize, using different colors.
Actually, pandas frame has its own equivalent of `numpy.where`, please look at this question: [pandas equivalent of np.where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579532/pandas-equivalent-of-np-where/38579700)