# Create new column in pandas using if statement

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in pandas using an if statement. I have this df:

```
df = {'Col1': [7,6,-9],
      'Col2': [0.5,0.5,0.5],
      'Col3': [5,4,3]}
```

If `Col1` is greater than 0, then I'd like to multiply `Col2` by `Col3` to create the new column, `Col4`. If `Col1` is not greater than 0, then I'd just like to return 0 as the column value.

Here is what I tried:

```
df['Col4'] = if df['Col1'] > 0:
    df['Col2'] * df['Col3']
else:
    0
```

I get the error: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

The final answer should look like this:

```
df = {'Col1': [7,6,-9],
      'Col2': [0.5,0.5,0.5],
      'Col3': [5,4,3],
      'Col4': [2.5,2,0]}
```

Note that because in `Col1` "-9" is not greater than 0, `Col4` should give 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `np.where`:

```
>>> df['Col4'] = np.where(df['Col1'] > 0, df['Col2'] * df['Col3'], 0)                                                   
>>> df
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0     7   0.5     5   2.5
1     6   0.5     4   2.0
2    -9   0.5     3   0.0
```

Basically, *where* `df['Col1']` is more than zero, the corresponding element in `Col4` will be `df['Col2'] * df['Col3']`. Otherwise, it will be zero.

There's also a `pd.DataFrame.where`, which I find a bit more unwieldy:

```
>>> df['Col4'] = (df['Col2'] * df['Col3']).where(df['Col1'] > 0, 0)
```

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579532/pandas-equivalent-of-np-where) for details.

Comment: you, sir, are a hero

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is invalid.  I think this is closer to what you wanted:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [7, 6, -9],
                   'Col2': [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
                   'Col3': [5, 4, 3]})
print(df)
print()

def product(row):
    if row['Col1'] > 0:
        return row['Col2'] * row['Col3']
    else:
        return 0


df['Col4'] = df.apply(product, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0     7   0.5     5   2.5
1     6   0.5     4   2.0
2    -9   0.5     3   0.0
```

Comment: you, sir, are also a hero