# Replace existing values by index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, replace

How do you use pandas to replace by index the values that you want to make negative?

My Code:

```
transFrom = allBills_df[allBills_df.Description == 'Transfer From Checking']['Amount']
transFromidx = allBills_df[allBills_df.Description == 'Transfer From Checking']['Amount'].index

new_values =  allBills_df[allBills_df.Description == 'Transfer From Checking']['Amount']*-1
```

Now that I have them as negative numbers, I want to replace them back into my 'allBills_df' by index.

```
Before:                    After:
    index  value            index  value
    77    1363.60           77    -1363.60 
    96     200.00           96     -200.00
    108    220.00           108    -220.00
    114   3000.00           114   -3000.00
    115    800.00           115    -800.00
    116    100.00           116    -100.00
    117     85.00           117     -85.00
    112   3000.00           112   -3000.00
```

Comment: I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. You can use `np.where` to assign a column different calculations based on an `if-else` statement. In this case, Amount*-1 if the description is 'Transfer From checking', else just the original Amount value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579532/pandas-equivalent-of-np-where

Answer (score 0):

I know I am close... but it just keeps looping through all of them...

```
oldData = allBills_df[allBills_df.Description == 'Transfer From Checking']['Amount']
oldDataIdx = allBills_df[allBills_df.Description == 'Transfer From Checking']['Amount'].index
newData = allBills_df[allBills_df.Description == 'Transfer From Checking']['Amount']*-1

for i in list(oldDataIdx):
    for j in list(newData):
        allBills_df.loc[i, 'Amount'] = j
```

Output:

```
    index   values
Out[111]: 
77    -200.0
96    -200.0
108   -200.0
114   -200.0
115   -200.0
116   -200.0
117   -200.0
112   -200.0
114   -200.0
116   -200.0
131   -200.0
136   -200.0
153   -200.0
154   -200.0
155   -200.0
156   -200.0
121   -200.0
123   -200.0
125   -200.0
```