# How to get boolean value in column based on a range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
cf1p2['Age Check'] = (cf1p2['Age']>18 & cf1p2['Age']<60)
```

I want to check if `cf1p2['Age']` is between 18 and 60 and need a result in `cf1p2['Age Check']` column

The current code is giving the following error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: kindly post data with expected results. Use this as a guide : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: `cf1p2['Age Check'] = cf1p2['Age'].between(18, 60, inclusive=False)`

Comment: try `cf1p2.loc[(cf1p2['Age']>18) & (cf1p2['Age']<60), 'new_col']  = value` you can also use `np.where` basically to turn the dataframe into a true false boolean you need to access or return it as an expression of a dataframe or use a pandas/numpy method that turns a series/dataframe into a boolean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas equivalent of np.where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579532/pandas-equivalent-of-np-where)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
cf1p2['Age Check'] = cf1p2['Age'].between(18, 60, inclusive=False)
```

You own solution should also work if you add some parenthesis around your conditions:

```
cf1p2['Age Check'] = (cf1p2['Age'] > 18) & (cf1p2['Age'] < 60)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello i came with a solution:

```
df['Age Check'] = np.where(df['age']>=18 & df['age']<=60, 'yes', 'no')
```

Let me know if helped!!

Answer (score 1):

Considering this example:

**df:**

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   52  41  23  53  22  22  39
1   48  49  58  48  45  57  32
2   38  49  48  25  32  22  27
3   46  34  43  52  50  32  30
4   59  47  49  22  53  31  38
5   49  49  58  37  28  31  34
6   31  29  28  41  39  36  47
7   34  55  52  39  32  25  55
8   34  21  48  22  22  53  42
9   44  23  57  52  29  54  43
```

---

```
df['age_check'] = (df['A'] > 58) & (df['A'] < 60)
df
```

---

**Result:**

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   age_check
0   52  41  23  53  22  22  39  False
1   48  49  58  48  45  57  32  False
2   38  49  48  25  32  22  27  False
3   46  34  43  52  50  32  30  False
4   59  47  49  22  53  31  38  True
5   49  49  58  37  28  31  34  False
6   31  29  28  41  39  36  47  False
7   34  55  52  39  32  25  55  False
8   34  21  48  22  22  53  42  False
9   44  23  57  52  29  54  43  False
```

Instead of

```
cf1p2['Age Check'] = (cf1p2['Age']>18 & cf1p2['Age']<60)
```

it should be

```
cf1p2['Age Check'] = (cf1p2['Age']>18) & (cf1p2['Age']<60)
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a pair of brackets to separate the two booleans.
Try: `cf1p2['Age Check'] = (cf1p2['Age']>18) & (cf1p2['Age']<60)`