# Do what np.select(condlist, choicelist) does but instead with pandas only

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have code and it works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


x = np.arange(10)
condlist = [x<3, x==5, x>5]
choicelist = [x, x**2, x**3]
a=np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

Now lets add:

```
y=pd.Series(x)
```

Lets now use `y` instead of `x`. Now we need to get same result (same content as `a` has, and it should be Series.) with **pandas only**, **and** the conditions and choices should be coded as above (use above code for coding conditions and choices). How to do that?

Comment: Expected output should be exactly same as code above gives in `a`. Data is in `y`.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas equivalent of np.where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579532/pandas-equivalent-of-np-where)

Comment: @AMC I have done research. That this is useful but it did not answers question. Answer below solves the problem.

Comment: Isn't the top answer to that question the same solution as the answer to this one?

Comment: @AMC It is close but different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

construct a dataframe from `choicelist` and use `df.where` with `condlist`

```
s = pd.DataFrame(choicelist).where(condlist).ffill().fillna(0).iloc[-1]

Out[99]:
0      0.0
1      1.0
2      2.0
3      0.0
4      0.0
5     25.0
6    216.0
7    343.0
8    512.0
9    729.0
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

---

If conditions are not overlapped, you may also use `sum`

```
s = pd.DataFrame(choicelist).where(condlist,0).sum()

Out[114]:
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      0
4      0
5     25
6    216
7    343
8    512
9    729
dtype: int64
```