# Error when replacing code with numpy variant with code with pandas variant

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here is a code:

```
# from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101845/compare-multiple-pandas-columns-1st-and-2nd-after-3rd-and-4rth-after-etc-wit
# from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474921/compare-two-columns-using-pandas?answertab=oldest#tab-top
# from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60099141/negation-in-np-select-condition
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'var1': ['a', 'b', 'c',np.nan, np.nan],
                   'var2': [1, 2, np.nan , 4, np.nan], 
                   'var3': [np.nan , "x", np.nan, "y", "z"],
                   'var4': [np.nan , 4, np.nan, 5, 6],
                   'var5': ["a", np.nan , "b", np.nan, "c"],
                   'var6': [1, np.nan , 2, np.nan, 3]
                 })



col1 = ["var1", "var3", "var5"]
col2 = ["var2", "var4", "var6"]
colR = ["Result1", "Result2", "Result3"]

s1 = df[col1].isnull().to_numpy()
s2 = df[col2].isnull().to_numpy()

conditions = [~s1 & ~s2, s1 & s2, ~s1 & s2, s1 & ~s2]
choices = ["Both values", np.nan, df[col1], df[col2]]

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.select(conditions, choices), columns=colR, index=df.index)], axis=1)
```

The result ( `df` ) looks like:

```
  var1  var2 var3  var4 var5  var6      Result1      Result2      Result3
0    a   1.0  NaN   NaN    a   1.0  Both values          NaN  Both values
1    b   2.0    x   4.0  NaN   NaN  Both values  Both values          NaN
2    c   NaN  NaN   NaN    b   2.0            c          NaN  Both values
3  NaN   4.0    y   5.0  NaN   NaN            4  Both values          NaN
4  NaN   NaN    z   6.0    c   3.0          NaN  Both values  Both values
```

It works but have problems with missing values in `choices` (more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570883/why-i-am-getting-nan-as-string-when-using-np-nan-and-missing-value-when-using-pd), but it is not that important to my current question).
Now I need to use instead of `np.select(conditions, choices)` code something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61091827/do-what-np-selectcondlist-choicelist-does-but-instead-with-pandas-only) (the idea is to use pandas instead of numpy in order to avoid problems described in a link above):

```
pd.DataFrame(choices).where(conditions).ffill().fillna(0).iloc[-1]
```

or this:

```
pd.DataFrame(choices).where(conditions,0).sum()
```

If I just replace the code part I am getting error:

```
runfile('D:/del/untitlejhgd0.py', wdir='D:/del')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-10cdf307d77c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/del/untitlejhgd0.py', wdir='D:/del')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/del/untitlejhgd0.py", line 29, in <module>
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame((pd.DataFrame(conditions).where(choices).ffill().fillna(0).iloc[-1]), columns=colR, index=df.index)], axis=1)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 488, in __init__
    mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 169, in init_ndarray
    values = prep_ndarray(values, copy=copy)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 295, in prep_ndarray
    raise ValueError("Must pass 2-d input")

ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

**Question:** How to replace code parts above in order to make code work?

Comment: Can you provide an example DF?

Comment: @Allen Thank you. Added. I do not know how I missed that.

Comment: I'm not experienced, but isn't it because the size of the data and conditions are different?
`print(np.size(choices),np.size(conditions))
4 60
`

Comment: Please describe in words what you are trying to do. Code is not too intuitive.

Comment: As @Parfait said please share your expected output.

Comment: @Parfait Expected output is already in question. It is just above the question (at the bottom).

Comment: @rpanai Expected output is already in question. It is just above the question (at the bottom).

Comment: @r-beginners There are 4 conditions and 4 choices.

Comment: @r-beginners In `conditions` sign `&` is use for grouping and `,` seprated each condition.

Comment: Moved output at the middle of the question.