# Filter dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using Python 3.9.

I'm trying to filter a pandas dataframe using `np.where` (np being numpy) but unable to do so. I don't understand what mistake I'm making.

Please could I request some help.

Code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

result_data = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")
print(result_data)

print(np.where(result_data['candle_high'] >= result_data['ema_close'] >= result_data['candle_low'], True, False))
```

I do see there are values in the dataframe that match the condition of ema_close being between candle_high & candle_low

[Online Jupyter notebook link](https://cocalc.com/projects/6f0d5f3c-6ef2-46ad-a079-5bc0744ca16c/files/Welcome%20to%20CoCalc.ipynb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try:

via `between()` method:

```
mask=result_data['ema_close'].between(result_data['candle_high'],result_data['candle_low'])

print(mask)
```

Comment: Thank you Anurag. Is there a way to set the value to something different than True/False

Comment: yes you can pass this in `np.where()` method and set your value accordingly for example `np.where(mask,'yes','no')`

Comment: Thank you Anurag. This helps. For some reason this wouldn't work initially. All good now

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
results_data.query('candle_high <= ema_close <= candle_low')
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
(df['A'] + df['B']).where((df['A'] < 0) | (df['B'] > 0), df['A'] / df['B'])
```

I think np.where(A, B) for A,B is numpy array.
see more https://stackoverflow.com/a/38579700/3981296