# applying np.where to datetime64[ns] changes dtype to object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a dataset containing a lot of dates. I only want to keep the dates larger than the date stated in the first column. Otherwise, I would like to replace them with NaT. This is an example of what the original dataset looks like:

```
    reference_date     date_1      date_2   ...
0   2017-01-20     2016-02-09         NaT        
1   2016-01-05            NaT         NaT
2   2016-01-13     2015-07-22  2016-02-29
3   2016-01-13     2016-04-18  2015-05-11
4   2016-01-11            NaT         NaT
...        ...            ...         ...
```

This is the output I would like to have:

```
        date_1      date_2   ...
0          NaT         NaT        
1          NaT         NaT
2          NaT  2016-02-29
3   2016-04-18         NaT
4          NaT         NaT
...        ...         ...
```

First I tried

```
df.loc[df['reference_date'] > df['date_1'], 'date_1'] = pd.NaT
```

which works for one column at the time but I want to apply this to a lot of columns.

I managed to replace all the unwanted dates with NaT using this code:

```
cols = df.columns[1:]
result = df[cols].apply(lambda x: np.where(x > df.reference_date, x, pd.NaT), axis = 0)
```

However, the original dates are transformed to another data type (originally it was datetime64[ns] and now it is object), resulting in large numbers instead of dates:

```
                 date_1               date_2   ...
0                   NaT                  NaT        
1                   NaT                  NaT
2                   NaT  1456704000000000000
3   1460937600000000000                  NaT
4                   NaT                  NaT
...                 ...                  ...
```

Any ideas what happens here and how I can keep the original date?

Many thanks

Comment: using [pandas equivalent of np.where](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38579532/10197418) should work fine: `df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.where(x > df.reference_date, pd.NaT), axis=0)`