# Deal with np.where and date condition

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, where-clause, timedelta

I have a variable "date_0" which correspond to date of infection in a certain period, and I have to create another variable "date_1" from the previous variable (date_0) with a date condition (>= 33 days). "date_0" and "date_1" are in format  %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.
So basically I should do a date condition like this :

`if df['date_1] >= 33 days then df['date_1] else df['date_0']`

And I do this :

`df['date_1']= np.where((df['date_1']>= 33d),  df['date_1'],df['date_O'])`

And I try also with this :

`df['date_1']= np.where((df['date_1'].days>= 33),  df['date_1'],df['date_O'])`

But I failed can you help me please ?

Comment: can you clarify what you aim for? do you want to select date1 if it is >= 33 days past date0, otherwise date0? also, it seems you are looking for [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html)

Comment: Exactly I want date_1 output if it is >= to 33 days otherwise output will be date_0. 33 days correspond to the difference between date_1 and date_0. I don't know if I have to use timedelta or a function like np.where or loc

Comment: it seems you're not far off, you can compare the timedelta `df['date_1']-df['date_0']` against `pd.Timedelta(days=33)`, or compare the days as integer like `(df['date_1']-df['date_0']).days` vs. `33`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [pandas equivalent to np.where](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38579532/10197418). Ex:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_0': [pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-02-01')],
                   'date_1': [pd.Timestamp('2022-01-29'), pd.Timestamp('2022-03-15')]})

df['days_diff'] = (df['date_1']-df['date_0']).dt.days

# date_select:
# use date 1 if the difference is greater equal 33 days else use date 0
df['date_select'] = df['date_1'].where(df['days_diff'] >= 33, df['date_0'])
```

```
df
      date_0     date_1  days_diff date_select
0 2022-01-01 2022-01-29         28  2022-01-01
1 2022-02-01 2022-03-15         42  2022-03-15
```