# How can I find the indices of values in a Numpy array that are between two threshold values?

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

I have a Numpy array `result.pvalues`, representing statistical p-values. I want to find the indices of p-values that are between 0.01 and 0.05.

I was able to find indices for p-values less than 0.05 like so:

```
print(np.where(result.pvalues < 0.05)[0])
```

But if I try to add the other condition like so:

```
print(np.where(result.pvalues < 0.05 and result.pvalues >= 0.01)[0])
```

I get an error that says:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Why does this error occur, and what does the message mean?

As far as I know, `a.any()` and `a.all()` determine if any (respectively all) elements of `a` are True. But I don't want that, I want to get an array of boolean results (to use `np.where` on them).

Comment: `result.pvalues < 0.05 and result.pvalues >= 0.01` should be `(result.pvalues < 0.05) & (result.pvalues >= 0.01)`

Comment: This does not work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arrays you need to use `numpy.logical_and`. This should work:

```
print(np.where(np.logical_and(result.pvalues < 0.05, result.pvalues >= 0.01))[0])
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but why? Why do you have to add additional function to just use the logical and?? It is not clear at all!

Comment: By the way, is there some other way to obtain the elements between 0.05 and 0.01 more easily??

Comment: The issue is that `result.pvalues >= 0.01` and `result.pvalues < 0.05` are boolean vectors and a simple 'and' does not know what element to compare, hence the suggestion you got to use either `a.any()` and `a.all()`, because that will allow to collapse the vector into a single true or false value. However what you need is a single boolean vector that is the element-wise `and` between the two conditions and this is done by `numpy.logical_and()`. I'd say this is the best way to do it.

Comment: I see. I would have never thought of that! So, this can't be done with any or all, because they give only one true or false result?

Comment: Exactly, `any` applied to each condition would give a `True` value if at least one element of the vector is true, while `all` would give a `True` if all elements of the vector is true, but this would be useless in your case.

Comment: I would also like to ask you (if you know of course) is it possible to obtain results from the summary of the Tukey test? Because the other problem with this function, that I was able to solve, but with two loops and more coding was to obtain all combination between the experimental variants. Otherwise it will only give me the single unique groups in a row.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that particular function

Comment: Is it possible for the same question, (df < 0.05) and (df >= 0.01) to somehow combine these two dataframes? For examle first I find the < 0.05 as array with true and false elements, and then I find the array >= 0.01, and then, somehow to find out the indeces, that are contain only the True value?

Comment: And also, is there a simpler way to obtain the indeces of the wanted elements from the dataframe (or the array)? Every time, when I have to work with Python I am terrified how to correctly convert between the different data types! For dataframe it is one and for numpy is other and finaly, for list and dictionaries, there is a third way to do this! Not to mention there are much more data types in python!

Comment: For the combination of the dataframe you really should post a question with a reproducible example, but I'm not sure I can help, while for the second one I'd suggest to avoid switching between dataframe and numpy arrays as much as possible. For where in dataframes you can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579532/pandas-equivalent-of-np-where)

Comment: "Why do you have to add additional function to just use the logical and?" - **You don't**. You can use `&` instead of `and`. Please see the linked duplicate. It also clearly explains why `and` doesn't work between arrays ("vectors" isn't correct terminology here).